# Executable pipe input?

Tags: xcode, arguments, pipe, executable

How to run executable in Xcode with piped input? For example:

```
echo "abc" | myexec
```

I know I can set arguments to my executable in the Executable [name] Info > Arguments tab, but there seems to be no option to prefix it or something.

I see "Use Pipe for standard input/output" in the General tab, but how to work with it? Doesn't seem to change a thing.

I'm using Xcode 3.2.6.

Comment: +1 for being one of the rare Xcode question posters who actually bothered to mention the version number !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the most elegant way, but could you have a Shell Script build phase that shunts the output of the first command into a file (`echo "abc" > tempfile`) and then call your executable with (`myexec < tempfile`)?

I haven't found much online yet besides [this now-broken link](http://algorithm.com.au/blog/files/2fd314dc0fa34252f7f8932bdccbdd7d-436.php) that explains the use of "Use Pipe for standard input/output".

Comment: As you put it: not exactly the most elegant solution, but it did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: So it is. All it really said was, more or less, "it can screw up your use of the debugger's console".